# Dynamic Dropdown SelectBox in Rails Issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a project in rails 4 where I am creating some dynamic drop downs. Below is all the code i have done for this dropdown. The drop downs are appearing, however not saving to the table and wont show up in the Show (and yes I have the proper ruby ie. `<%= @reports.site_id %>`.

I am not sure what to do from here and I am a bit of a rails noob, but have worked through tutorials and classes on the language.

My Form Select Box Looks Like this:

```
`<%= collection_select( :site, :site_id, Site.all, :id, :site_call_sign, {}, { :multiple => false %>`
```

The above select box dose get data from the site table but wont save that data to the reports table??`

My Controller looks like this:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reports
  # GET /reports.json
  def index

    @search = ReportDateSearch.new(params[:search])
    @reports = @search.scope

    @reports = Report.all


  # Adds CSV Downloader to Residents
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { render text: @reports.to_csv }
    end
  end

  # GET /reports/1
  # GET /reports/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /reports/new
  def new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  # GET /reports/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reports
  # POST /reports.json
  def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.save
        format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @report }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reports/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reports/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.update(report_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @report }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reports/1
  # DELETE /reports/1.json
  def destroy
    @report.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reports_url, notice: 'Report was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  # Adds CSV Uploader Method to Application
    def import
      Report.import(params[:file])
      redirect_to reports_path, notice: "Report(s) Added Successfully"
    end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_report
      @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def report_params
      params.require(:report).permit(:date, :site_id, :user_id, :type_of_report, :type_of_incident, :report)
    end
end
```

my model looks like this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :site

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Report.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end

  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |report|
        csv << report.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

My Show Page Looks Like:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>

<strong>Date:</strong>

<%= @report.date %>

</p>

<p>

<strong>Site:</strong>

<%= @report.site_id %>

</p>

<p>

<strong>Created By:</strong>

<%= @report.user_id %>

</p>

<p>

<strong>Type of report:</strong>

<%= @report.type_of_report %>

</p>

<p>

<strong>Type of incident:</strong>

<%= @report.type_of_incident %>

</p>

<p>

<strong>Report:</strong>

<%= @report.report %>

</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_report_path(@report) %> |

<%= link_to 'Back', reports_path %>
```

not too sure where I'm going wrong here.Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you edit your question to show more of your controller? Specifically we need to see the action does the actual saving of the report.

Comment: @SeanHuber I have added my entire controller... as stated in opening question i am still new to rails and thought the full view would be better than a crap shoot guess as to what you would want to see. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, the issue could be happening for a variety of reasons, and I may need to ask for more info.  See my initial answer below and let me know if that works. If not, we'll have to look at the views for your new and edit actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the first parameter if your collection_select call from `:site` to `:report`:

```
<%= collection_select( :report, :site_id, Site.all, :id, :site_call_sign, {}, { :multiple => false } %>
```

My initial guess is that your form is passing up site_id as `params[:site_id]` instead of `params[:report][:site_id]`, which is the format you'd need based on your strong parameters method in your controller:

```
def report_params
  params.require(:report).permit(:date, :site_id, :user_id, :type_of_report, :type_of_incident, :report)
end
```

If it doesn't work, one thing you can do to help debug the issue is look at your rails console and see exactly the format that your form parameters are being sent from your view to the controller.  Putting a couple puts statements in your action can help you better compare `params` versus `report_params`:

```
def create
  puts "Params: #{params.inspect}"
  puts "Report Params: #{report_params.inspect}"

  @report = Report.new(report_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @report.save
      format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @report }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Look in your server console for the output of those 2 puts statements.  If you see site_id in params and not in report_params, you'll know your strong parameters method has filtered it out.

Comment: That worked perfectly! i was in the mind set that <%= collection_select( :site, <= referenced the table i was pulling the column from and not that, thats where it would be stored! i appreciate your assistance with this very much!